# not able to enter my mobile phone for security verification

Tags: admin

I am trying to set up a Google Workspace.  But, when I try to log into the admin console, I receive an error message saying that suspicious activity has been noticed on my account.  I then enter my mobile number and it refuses to accept it by saying that the number has been used too many times.  I'm assuming that means that I've created too many email accounts.  How can I rectify the situation?  I only have one mobile phone number.

I entered my mobile phone number and it was rejected.